# Как уменьшить размер иконки в svg через css?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Вот код:

```
.dropdown-item:nth-of-type(3)::after {
    content: url(../img/icon-bootstrap4.svg);
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Как пишут умные люди https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/ - это невозможно

Answer (score 2):

Сам долго бился с SVG и нашёл самый действенный и безотказный метод:

```
transform: scale();
```

в ту сторону, какую вам нужно, всё работает.

Answer (score 1):

svg в content ведет себя очень странно, я с ним так и не смог совладать. Перенесите его в background

```
.dropdown-item:nth-of-type(3)::after {
    content: "";
    background: url(../img/icon-bootstrap4.svg) no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```